# Webpack url and file loaders don't working on Angular 2 required component styles

Tags: sass, angular, requirejs, webpack

I’m building an app with angular 2, sass and webpack and I’m having troubles with url on sass files that are required inside each component (using require); it doesn’t take those files and copy it to assets folder and don’t modify the url to the builded css styles.
It work's correctly when I use import and with the assets inside html component's.

loaders:

```
        ...{
            test: /\.html$/,
            loader: 'html'
        },
        {
            test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/,
            loader: 'file?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
        },
        {
            test: /\.scss/,
            exclude: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?sourceMap!sass?sourceMap')
        },
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            include: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
            loaders: ['raw', 'resolve-url', 'sass?sourceMap']
        }...
```

Require styles:

```
...
styles: [require('./hero-image.scss')]
template: require('./hero-image.component.html')
...
```

Sass

```
...
background: url('../../../public/img/hero-bg.jpg');
...
```

Here the loaders (when build) should copy hero-bg.jpg to /assets/ and in the builded css the background should be `/assets/hero-bg.jpg` but it doesn't copy the image to assets folders and css builded remains like the sass.

**NOTE:** When I use import instead of require (modifying the loaders rules of course) at this point it works correctly.
Inside the html component (hero-image.component.html) I have this `<img src="../../../public/img/btn-google-play.jpg" />` and it work's correctly too.

I try with [this angular 2 starter pack](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter) and the issue also happens.

Thanks for helping, I really appreciate it.

Edit: I forgot to mention that this also happens using only css (without sass) and following the [official angular documentation about webpack](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After a lot of research and many attempts I found an approach using the [exports-loader](https://github.com/webpack/exports-loader) that work's and can be easily updated.

```
{
   test: /\.scss$/,
   include: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
   loaders: ['exports-loader?module.exports.toString()', 'css', 'sass']
}
```

Thanks @BobSponge for your help, you guided me in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks David! I'm glad I found this after hours of trying solutions that don't work =)

Answer (score 3):

Looks like incorrect config example in Angular docs.

Neither of this loaders process `url()` in css and publish assets to destination folder: `'raw', 'resolve-url', 'sass'`.
Despite the name, `resolve-url` loader just replacing relative urls to suitable for `css-loader`.

So, you should add `css-loader` to the last scss loader's config:

```
{
   test: /\.scss$/,
   include: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
   loaders: ['css', 'resolve-url', 'sass?sourceMap']
}
```

Styles require will changed to:

```
styles: [require('./hero-image.scss').toString()]
```

---

From [docs](https://github.com/webpack/css-loader):
`@import` and `url(...)` [in css files] are interpreted like `require()` and will be resolved by the `css-loader`.

Comment: It doesn't work :(, this breaks the generated styles because add's js code inside the raw. `module.exports = "exports = module.exports = require(...`

Comment: Sorry, did not notice that `css-loader` produces not plain css. Try to remove `'raw'`.

Comment: Will not work because angular styles receive is an array of strings, so I get an error when try to render.

Comment: Thank you very much @BobSponge, your solution work's but I don't like that I have to modify all components for adding the toString, I found a way to achieve this with extract-loader so it can be easily maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to `exports-loader?module.exports.toString()` is to use the [to-string-loader](https://github.com/gajus/to-string-loader) mentioned in the [css-loader readme](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#tostring)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, link only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow, you can improve this answer by taking vital parts of the link and putting it into your answer, this makes sure your answer is still an answer if the link gets changed or removed :)