# Webpack: Cannot load CSS with url() imports

Tags: html, css, angularjs, webpack, loader

Spent one hour trying to solve the problem, still clueless.

I am using Webpack to build an Angular 2 app, and I'm trying to import some CSS files from PrimeUI. Unfortunately when building it spits out this message:

```
ERROR in ./~/primeui/themes/omega/theme.css
Module build failed: /home/mc128k/node/angular2-webpack-starter/node_modules/primeui/themes/omega/fonts/roboto-v15-latin-regular.eot:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { c?

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:513:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/mc128k/node/angular2-webpack-starter/node_modules/primeui/themes/omega/theme.css:6:156)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.loaderContext.exec (/home/mc128k/node/angular2-webpack-starter/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:88:7)
    at Object.module.exports (/home/mc128k/node/angular2-webpack-starter/node_modules/to-string-loader/src/to-string.js:6:54)
 @ ./src/main.browser.ts 2:0-41
```

So what happens here? The CSS gets parsed correctly by the style loader defined in the webpack configuration:

```
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    loaders: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader']
},
```

If I try to remove this snippet a lot of errors get generated, so this works. But if the CSS imports stuff like this:

```
src: url('fonts/roboto-v15-latin-regular.eot');
```

Then the compilation fails. It looks like webpack is trying to parse the font. Happens with every other file, like woff and gif images.

Apparently the other loaders get ignored, but it's weird because they look correct (and I tried copy-pasting lots of snippets here).

```
  {
    test: /\.(ttf|gif|svg)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/,
    loader: 'file-loader'
  },
  {
    test: /\.(eot)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/,
    loader: 'file-loader'
  },
```

So... I'm lost. Tried studying the docs, checking other answers and so on, but I still don't get why webpack doesn't match a loader when seeing the `url()` function in the CSS.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you use the `resolve-url` ([resolve-url-loader in webpack](https://github.com/bholloway/resolve-url-loader)) ?

I use the following loader for css :

```
{
      test: /\.css$/,
      loaders: ['style','css?sourceMap!postcss!resolve-url']
    },
```

Comment: [deleted, searching more info before asking again]

Comment: Have you `npm install resolve-url-loader` ? 
Also take a look to https://github.com/webpack/css-loader .

Comment: Ok, solved by installing `resolve-url resolve-url-loader`, then changing the CSS line to `loaders: ['style', 'css', 'resolve-url']` and tweaking the image loader regex (it wasn't loading the ?stuff=v0.3.2 part) `/\.(ttf|gif|svg|png)(\?[a-z0-9\=\.]+)?$/,`. Now the compiler works and the browser throws an error about 'styles to be an array of strings'. Will update here if I find a solution.

Comment: Update: Something conflicts with Angular's `styleUrls` definition, when it's used it spits out the error `Expected 'styles' to be an array of strings`. This is because the pipeline included `to-string`, but now it won't work anymore. Just apply the following loader pipeline for css: `loaders: ['exports-loader?module.exports.toString()', 'style', 'css', 'resolve-url']`, thanks to [this stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37402003/webpack-url-and-file-loaders-dont-working-on-angular-2-required-component-style).